# mootools getElements failed

Tags: javascript, mootools

i want to access a form with mootools.
My html code looks like:

```
  <table border="0">

        <tr>
          <td>username</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="username" value="bla "/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>password</td>
          <td><input type="password" id="password"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="project"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" id="login" value="login"/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

my JavaScript like:

```
  window.addEvent('domready', function() {  
        //We are going to fill this with Mootools goodness  

  var jsonReq = new Request.JSON({
  url: 'test.php',
  method: 'post',
  data: {
   username: $('username').value,
    password: $('password').value,
    project : $('project').value
  },
    onSuccess: function( response ) 
    {
       if ( response.status )
       {
        document.location = "home.html"   
       }
       else
       {
          $('response').addClass('error');
           $('response').set('html', response.message);
         alert( "Msg" + response.message ); 
       }
    },
   // onRequest: function() { alert('Request made. Please wait...'); },
    onError: function( response, err ) { alert('Faiure' + response + err); },
    onFailure: function( response ) { alert('Faiure' + response); },

});

$('login').addEvent('click',function( event ){
     event.stop();
     jsonReq.send();
});

    });
```

the problem is, if the value attribute is set, i can retriev this in my php script, but no changes.

so i alwayes see username=bla but no changes...
could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

because the data object gets populated at domready state. at that time, there is no value.

you can do in the submit handler:

```
jsonReq.setOptions({
    data: document.id('someform')
}).send();
```

you can pass an actual form element to data and it will serialize it for you. else, do what you did above